# Operator norm in $L^2$ of $Af(x)=x^{\alpha}f(x^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I am trying to solve this exercise but I have some difficulties.

In $L^2(0,1)$ we consider the operator $Af(x)=x^{\alpha}f(x^2)$, for $\alpha \ge \frac{1}{2}$. Find the operators of $A$, $A^*A$, $AA^*$ and the norm of $A$.

I have calculated the following but I am not sure if it is correct.
$A^*f(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha}f(\sqrt x)}{2}$
Regarding the norm of the operator $A$ I have found the upper bound $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$
but I have no idea on how to compute the lower bound.
If someone could give me some help I would be very grateful.

Comment: Regarding the norm, consider using integration by substitution to obtain a statement of the type $||Af||_{L^2}= ||f \cdot g||_{L^2}$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the hint.

Comment: $\int_0^1 x^{2\alpha} f(x^2)^2 dx = \int_0^1 y^{\alpha} f(y)^2 \frac{1}{2y} dy $ via integration by substitution.

Comment: Thank you! I have done this computation, shouldn't it be $1/(2\sqrt y) $? I don't know how to use the hint you gave me in the first comment. Please could you explain in to me? Thanks again.

Comment: Yup, you are right. That was a typo my bad. And now you just have to bring this integral in the form of an L2 norm and maybe use something like Cauchy Schwartz and so on....
Regarding the first comment your g is now $g(x)=x^\alpha \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: I see, but using Cauchy Schwartz don't I find an upper bound? I just need the lower one. Moreover doesn't g has to be the square root of the one you wrote?

Comment: It depends on the norm how you write $g$ :) Just look for a global upper bound of g, then you can easily estimate, or reason why g is bounded on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119042/discussion-between-giuseppe-knecht-and-max).